# mysql repair myisam table give a error 127

Tags: mysql

My server have an hdd fault. Due to this one table of DB was corrupted.
I've tried to use myisamchk -r /path/to/table_name.MYI to repair it. After executing i have a message `myisamchk: error: 127 for record at pos 1835056`
Can you any one help to repair a table?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Start the mysql server and login as root
2. Run the **CHECK TABLE** command with the **EXTENDED** option

   **CHECK TABLE** table_name **EXTENDED**
3. Then run the **REPAIR TABLE** command with the **EXTENDED** option

   **REPAIR TABLE** table_name **EXTENDED**

After the repair check the table again to make sure it has been repaired. If the table is corrupt still, then, if you have a backup of the db, you can delete the table and copy the backup table in its place. If you don't have a backup and the data is critical, you can get a tool like ***Stellar Phoenix Database Recovery For MySQL*** to try and recover your data. I have used Stellar before and love their recovery tools.